# Calculating the distance from each point in one layer to the nearest point in another layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, distance

I am trying to find the average distance from several points in a layer to points in another layer. I am using ArcMap Basic - I know there is a way to do this using the Advanced version of ArcMap but was wondering if anyone knew a workaround for Basic (if it exists).

Comment: Are you trying to find an ArcGIS for Desktop Basic workaround to [**Near**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) or to [**Point Distance**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001r000000)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the ArcPy answer will be to SearchCursor through your two feature classes and use an InsertCursor to write a new table with values calculated according to this algorithm:

```
import math
dist = math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
```

which is the **[Python equivalent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000011000000.htm)** of AML's INVDISTANCE function.

This approach would give you the distance from every point in one feature class to every point in another.  If you are only interested in those up to a certain distance just write records when the distance returned is greater than this threshold.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to find the 1st nearest point, the easiest method would be to use [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) with the `match_option` set as `CLOSEST`. This will return the attributes of the `join_features` point closest to each `target_features` point.

If you need to find many nearest points (e.g. the 1st through 10th nearest points) to each point and you have lots of points (n > 100,000), it will be much faster to create a Python script that uses the [cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) module from SciPy.