# Alternate of Near Distance Tool of ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, proximity

I have basic license level of ArcGIS 10.1, and near distance tool is not available with it. Can anyone please suggest of another similar purpose tool, under basic license, to get distance of one polygon from another polygon or any workaround?

Comment: What file or database source are you using? If oracle or postgres you can do queries for feature to feature distances without ArcGIS.

Comment: I am using *.shp files created within ArcGIS.

Comment: Have you reviewed this [**previous question**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54630/calculating-the-distance-from-each-point-in-one-layer-to-the-nearest-point-in-an/54640#54640)?  It should offer a way to get distances between points converted from polygon vertices to identify how far the nearest vertices of two polygons are to each other. Alternatively, check out the CLOSEST match_option of [**Spatial Join**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) which may or may not meet your precise requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Point Distance](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm) tool from ET Geowizard, however you would have to convert the from polygon layer to a point centroid or point feature class first.

Comment: Thanks. Although I was looking for something within ArcGIS framework, but this will do it as an alternative.

Comment: @lbe, thanks comments are not necessary, instead you may up vote helpful answers.

Comment: Bear in mind if your input layer has more than 100 features, you will need to register.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [arcpy geometry objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geometry/018z00000070000000/) and [cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/). Each of [PointGeometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/PointGeometry/018z00000039000000/), [Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/), and [Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon/018z00000061000000/) have a distanceTo(other geometry) method.

Answer (score -1):

I know this can be done in R, but am not yet sure how. 
Different packages exist for doing it between points and (points, lines, polygons).
This one does points to line, for example.