# Measuring distances between many points in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance

So I'm new to this, the answer is probably really simple.

I have a point map of X Y data points (one for each participant) for a certain activity.  I also have a shape file of zip codes, which I then made a point file out of this with the centroid for each zip code.  I want to measure the distance from the point for the activity to the zip code that corresponds to each specific participant.  I joined the attribute tables for these so that each participant has the a column for the lat, and long for the activity and the zip code lat and long.  I must be close.

How do I ask ArcGIS to measure the distance between these points?

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

1) Try using the [NEAR](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) function in the toolbox

2) Try using a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000)

3) Try using creating "[Euclidean Distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000)" rasters from each origin and then [bringing these values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000) into the points.

1 or 2 is most likely your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention your license level, but if it is Advanced I would recommend trying the [Point Distance (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001r000000) tool which:

> Determines the distances from input point features to all points in
>   the near features within a specified search radius.

However, if you have a Basic or Standard license then it is possible to achieve the same functionality using the ArcPy workaround at:

[Performing Point Distance analysis using Basic level license of ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113446/performing-point-distance-analysis-using-basic-level-license-of-arcgis-for-deskt)

You also do not mention the coordinate system of your data, although you do mention it having lat/long columns, so you may need to get it into a Projected Coordinate System if you need units of meters or feet rather than decimal degrees.

Comment: I have a student version of ArcGIS, I'm not sure but that probably the basic level license. So to measure the distance between the two points, I need to have the same Projected Coordinate System for both layers right? I'm having an issue with that because I got the point data off of Google Maps for the lat/long and the GCS for that to display correctly is GCS_WGS_1984. If I try to specify a Projection System (my other layer uses USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic) the GCS automatically changes so the points disappear off of the zip code areas.